# Gekko Python: Any way to export the model for debugging purposes?

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I have a gekko model that is not producing the solution I expect. It would be great to print the model in a readable form for debugging purposes (much like printing an LP format from CPLEX).

Is this possible?

My model solves perfectly in Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `m.open_folder()` to open the run directory where `gk0_model.apm` is located. This is a text version of the model that Gekko produces. Here is a simple application:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()                 # create GEKKO model

print('--------- Follow local path to view files --------------')
print(m.path)               # show source file path
m.open_folder()
print('-'*56)

u = m.Param(value=5,name='u')  # define parameter
x = m.Var(name='s')            # define variable
m.Equation(x==u)               # define equation
m.options.SOLVER = 1           # change solver (1=APOPT,3=IPOPT)
m.solve(disp=False)
print('x: ' + str(x.value))    # print variable value
```

The following output is produced by the script:

```
--------- Follow local path to view files --------------
C:\Users\johnh\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3oqof67rgk_model0
--------------------------------------------------------
x: [5.0]
```

Opening `gk0_model.apm` with a text editor shows the model file in APMonitor format:

```
Model
Parameters
    u = 5
End Parameters
Variables
    s = 0
End Variables
Equations
    s=u
End Equations
End Model
```

The APM model can be solved with [APM Matlab](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/MATLAB) or through a [web-browser interface](https://apmonitor.com/online/view_pass.php).

Comment: Wow that is very helpful! Thank you for taking the time to share.