# Gekko in a Docker Container

Tags: docker, gekko, mpc

I was interested to know if there is a Gekko container available.
Idea is to have a gekko MPC in a docker that can be easily configured with an interface to load a model, do tuning and visualize the results for a realtime application.

Comment: What's wrong with using a python image as base, and then install gekko, creating a custom image?

Comment: Wondering if there are already some existing tools available to interact with a gekko based docker, so that I don't have to write my own.  Like a web ui to configure an MPC and deploy it to run as a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tutorial on how to [Dockerize a Python program](https://medium.com/swlh/dockerize-your-python-command-line-program-6a273f5c5544) that is run from a Command Line Interface (CLI). Include `gekko` in the requirements.txt file. This uses a [minimal version of Python](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) that is designed for docker containers.

```
FROM python:3.9-slim
RUN useradd --create-home --shell /bin/bash app_user
WORKDIR /home/app_user
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
USER app_user
COPY . .
CMD ["bash"]
```

There is also a two part series on how to package applications in a Docker container with [Part 1 - Using Docker Desktop and Docker Hub](https://www.docker.com/blog/using-docker-desktop-and-docker-hub-together-part-1/) and [How to Build and Test Your Docker Images in the Cloud with Docker Hub](https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-build-and-test-your-docker-images-in-the-cloud-with-docker-hub/).

A few things to consider:

- Include `m.path` (GEKKO run-time directory) in the Docker PATH: [Compiling Gekko with Pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66181211/compiling-gekko-with-pyinstaller)  The `m._path` value can be changed from the `tmp` directory to something else.
- More information about the Gekko run directory: [Gekko Python: Any way to export the model for debugging purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71769888/gekko-python-any-way-to-export-the-model-for-debugging-purposes/)
- The Gekko GUI requires Flask webserver and other components to run: [How do I display solution in GEKKO GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73729774/how-do-i-display-solution-in-gekko-gui) This will increase the size and complexity of the Docker container.
- Include communication protocols such as [Modbus](https://apmonitor.com/dde/index.php/Main/ModbusTransfer) or [OPC UA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPC_Unified_Architecture) to read and write values to and from a Programmable Logic Controller or Distributed Control System.

Every MPC application that I've created is so customized with a particular model for a particular application that it doesn't seem practical to create a general-purpose Docker container. If the application can be developed once and copied to many similar systems (e.g. MPC to replace PID control) then a Docker container may make sense to ease deployment.